# Excel rendered from SSRS loses currency symbold when viewed on iPhone in UK

Tags: iphone, ios5, reporting-services

Our reports format the currency dynamically.  So in the result-set there is a column called CurrencyFormatString.  This is applied to the appropriate fields via FORMAT(FieldName,CurrencyFormatString)

Everything seems to work fine until the report is rendered to Excel and the file is viewed on an iPhone.  For our UK Customers they see $ instead £ for the currency symbol.  Of course, it works just fine on an Andriod device.

If I take the correct formatting mask, and manually put it into an Excel cell. Save it and send to myself it works fine.  There seems to be something going on with the Currency setting on the cell overriding the format.

This comes out in the Column CurrencyFormatString: £#,##0.00;(£#,##0.00)

Export to Excel, open and R-Click Properties you see: [$-10409]£#,##0.00;-£#,##0.00

when SSRS renders the Excel.  I don't know what that first part in brackets is, Im guessing it has something to do with the Currency setting which is set to $.

Any ideas on getting the proper format to propagate to the iPhone?  This is using SSRS 2008.  I havent tried on newer versions of SSRS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question appears to be, you can't.

It also appears that the SSRS included with SQL Server 2012 now defaults to rendering in .xslx which the native iPhone Email app can't open anyways.

If you, your company or customers use Android, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can trick Excel by exporting an excel formula.

In the SSRS report, if you use something like this sort of formula:
"=TEXT(" + FieldName + ",""£#,##;-£#,##"")"

On the report it will look like this if you view it in html renderer:
=TEXT(55.00,"£#,##;-£#,##")

When exported to excel, the excel formula parser will kick in and you will get
£55.00

Ugly workaround I know. -1 to iPhone's Excel app.

Comment: Doesnt seem to be working, all I ever get to display is #Error.  I tried pasting exactly what you have there, and replaced the FieldName with the correct field name and didnt work.  Tried different variations and still didnt work.

Comment: Can you try breaking it down, i.e.
In the iPhone Excel, is it possible to put in this formula:=TEXT(55.00,"£#,##;-£#,##") and verify it shows you

Comment: If that works can you try a hard code version of the SSRS field and export it to excel on the iPhone: ="=TEXT(55.00,""£#,##;-£#,##"")"
Making sure that SSRS doesn't try and interpret that as a formula and that it's just text.(Note the two = symbols there, as well as the pairs of quotation marks surrounding the format string, the first quotation escapes the second to make it display as part of the string rather than terminating it)

Comment: This article might help too
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159220%28SQL.90%29.aspx

I think it will just be a matter of building the string the right way. It is working for me on PC version of Excel, I don't have an iPhone to test that

Comment: Im going to work on this today and get back to you.  It works if I put the format into Excel, save and send to iPhone.  The problem stems from taking a varchar column which spits out the Format string, and then using a function in SSRS to format the other columns.  But it does seem like you say, I should be able to "trick" excel into doing what I want.

Comment: Ugh, still doesn't work when SSRS renders the table. I get =TEXT(55.00,"£#,##;-£#,##") in the cell. What's awesome is, I can open the SSRS rendered Excel, copy the =TEXT(55.00,"£#,##;-£#,##") from one cell, paste into the one next to it, and I get the £55. SSRS must not render a true "Excel" file, I guess it just plops the data onto a spread sheet in Exce

Comment: Oh I know what it is. When you enter a formula into Excel, pressing enter makes it run, alternatively pressing F9 makes all formulas run.
It's definately creating a proper Excel file, it's just not running the formulas. That sucks.
In your answer below you said they are opening it with the iPhone Email app. Is there not an Excel app that would work?

Comment: There probably is, but I'm sure this "feature" is not listed as any of the main features in the description of the app. Don't think the company would allow me to start downloading apps and testing them.  Though I guess I could Email the developer and see what they have to say.