# Cannot open excel files exported from SSRS on iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, reporting

I know this is a long standing issue with microsoft but I have yet to hear definitively anywhere that this issue has been resolved with a specific version of SSRS or Visual Studio. I build SSRS reports in visual studio (2013  version 12.0.31101.00 update 4) and I've been googling this issue all over the internet and have yet to find an official answer to whether there is a solution or effective work around for this issue. After the reports are run and exported, once they are saved, if email to an iphone, they cannot be opened? Does anyone have a definitive answer as of now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get around this issue by activating SSRS's Excel 2003 renderer in the Reporting Server config. This will only be of benefit if you're not after later features in your Excel output, but a simple report should be fine.

Details of how to find and edit the rsreportserver.config file here: [Modify a Reporting Services Configuration File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/modify-a-reporting-services-configuration-file-rsreportserver-config). Be very careful; even though this change is quite simple heed the caution on using a plain text editor.

I'm quoting settings from the SSRS 2016 SQL Server Standard Edition (13.0.420.2).

In the config file find the  section. It contains a list that looks similar to that of the SSRS Scheduler pages Render Format, however some entries have a 'Visible="false"' property. This includes the "EXCEL" (Excel 2003) edition. Nice of them to keep it in there though, right??? I simply modified it to 'Visible="true"' and saved.

```
        <Render>
        <Extension Name="EXCELOPENXML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ExcelRendering"/>
        <Extension Name="EXCEL" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelRenderer.ExcelRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ExcelRendering" Visible="true"/>
```

The EXCELOPENXML edition is the default live one that's not being rendered on the mobile device correctly and the EXCEL edition is the one you're now making available.

Once saved ensure that you can browse immediately to the Reporting Server site. An error in the config format will cause it to have issues instantly so you'll want to be on top of it. No need to restart the server for this. If you have an issue restore your changes from the backup that MS recommended you make.

The end result is that you should be able to open a generated Excel sheet on the previewer on iPhone. In my case I lost some formatting - mostly borders - but the structure was intact. It opens properly formatted on the PC.

If you have further issues you may wish to note that there are parameters you can pass to the Excel renderer device file. See [Excel Device Information Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/excel-device-information-settings) for the details. It doesn't state which edition of the device files these apply to but I'd guess the older edition is limited in this respect. You might find that using the new renderer with the right parameter works out, but it didn't in my case.

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I ended up doing. I've switched the file type to excel 2003 which did solve the issue. Good answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with iPhone not supporting .xlsx files in email ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568206/excel-rendered-from-ssrs-loses-currency-symbold-when-viewed-on-iphone-in-uk)). These Excel attachments work fine on Android and PC. Workarounds might be to email a link to the file or, if the results are small, just embed them in the body of the email. Or even export as .csv depending on your requirements.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue specifically with .xlsx files as I've sent my own iphone excel .xlsx files and opened them without an issue. It's only the files which are exported from SSRS which seem to open with an unreadable error.

Answer (score 0):

on the iphone, you can download the file then open with> the Excel app